# Washing machine agitator not working

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

Over the past few months, the agitator on my Maytag LAT9416AAE washer has worked intermittently. Normally, I could get it to resume working by pushing and pulling the selector/start knob a few times or moving it back to the beginning of the wash cycle. Now, it has stopped agitating altogether and no amount of coaxing will make it work.

The agitator engages with the spline as it is supposed to. I removed the front of the cabinet and ran a cycle. The motor does not even attempt to turn the belt when the agitator should be activated. However, it works fine to perform the spin cycle. The washer fills and drains without a problem and the timer advances through the entire cycle.

Is it possible that the timer is not sending the signal to run the motor during the agitator phase? Or is there a method to isolate the failed component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test the timer using a multimeter and this schematic:

[image]

All the circuits showed connectivity when tripped by the mechanism. I reinstalled the timer and discovered that pulling hard on the timer knob would make the agitation cycle work. Evidently, the timer is still the issue even if the circuitry is not.

Comment: In the end, I replaced the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your orbital transmission. But, what brief research I did implies the transmission is a common replacement on these, at almost $300. So, get a new washer.

A simple test on yours was to see if you could spin the big pulley by hand. It would turn only if still "good". The motor is trying to spin the transmission but it's completely locked up. But, if you can wiggle it, beat it with a sledge hammer or ask it nicely to move then move it & try an agitation run to see if it engages. If so, then still get a new washer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I can spin it by hand.

Comment: Sorry, just getting back from a suspension. Any luck with anything? I wish I was more familiar with your machine. Get a new motor is what I'm thinking, since I've never had a Timer go bad on me with any brand. Or, of course, get an Appliance Repairer...same price.